# KUbuntu - How can I sort in "Icon View Mode"

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I am using Kubuntu 18.04.1

Default File Browser is Dolphin.

I know I can sort in **Details View mode**.

However, I want to right click in **Icon View Mode** and sort by name or type.

I can not find this option by default in Dolphin.

[image]

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dolphin in two modes by means of toggling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>:
In one mode, you get the classic `File`, `Edit`, `View` etc menu bar. In the other mode, you'll just have a single `Control` dropdown (accessed by pressing ☰ (marked in red) in the first image.

I believe the images are self-explanatory for sorting files in icon-view mode:

## In "control" mode

[image: in control mode]

## In classic menu bar mode

[image: in menu bar mode]